# Rendering an aspx page in razor view (cshtml)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I need to render a crystal report in a asp.net mvc application. Since mvc does not provide the support for reportviewer.I'm forced to redirect to an aspx page.However i'm losing the layout.cshtml menu in that redirect .

Is there anyway we can do show the partial view of aspx page on the same razor page , in the same window?

Iframe is one solution that I'm aware but do not want to use it as it is not a good practice to use iframes in modern apps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if iframe isn't a practical option for you, then you perhaps should consider creating a WebForms Master page specifically for your report page(s).

Then on that Master page, you can set its default **PlaceHolder** controls to **invisible** and explicitly render the Razor layout view within server tags.

```
<%   var buildTitle = new StringBuilder();
     var buildMain = new StringBuilder();
     TitleContent.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(buildTitle)));
     ViewBag.Title = buildTitle.ToString().Trim();
     MainContent.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(buildMain)));
     ViewBag.MainContent = buildMain.ToString().Trim();
%>
<%= Html.Partial("YourRazorLayoutView", viewData: ViewData)%>
```

For more details, please go check out this [blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3).